# How to delete node in javascript without where parent node is null

Tags: javascript

I creating couple of `Image` classes in my javascript code (as I understand - it is ordinary `img` node) but (it is important) did not attached it to DOM. I using it to check preloading status and drawa on `canvas` after that.

For now I want to be able to interrupt preloading process, so, as I ubderstood I need to delete node where `node.complete === false`.Is there way to do it without creating another fake element and use it as parent for all images? Could I just delete node without parent? Or removing node does not interrupt HTTP request for image resource?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the parent node is null then the element is *not* in the DOM and does not need to be removed from the DOM - and removing an image node from the DOM will not affect it loading.

Simply:

1. Set the `Image.src` to something else such as an empty string (this is the best that can be done to tell the browser to "stop loading" the resource), and;
2. Don't maintain any strong references to the element

The Element will then be "deleted" or "garbage collected" automatically at some point after it is no longer reachable by JavaScript (see #2).

I believe that there *may* be an race condition between any `onload` events and setting `Image.src` to the empty string. If it is absolutely important the loading "is aborted" - even when it was successful - make sure to check the `src` property (or another "abort" flag) again in the onload/complete checking handler.